# How can i change the both value change and function call in a single onChange

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, state, use-state

Here is the code, and i want to call apifetcher at the same time when the value of the city changes.how to do that?? is it possible
The value of the city should replace the 'q' value. And after that both the city and the API are passing to an another file.what should I add or remove.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Cities from "./citylist";
import Autocomplete from "@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import Content from "./content";

const SearchBar = () => {
  const [city, setcity] = useState("");
  const [api, setapi] = useState(
    `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=Kurunegala,LK& mode=json&appid=5c4420d5c8a61c16e5ee37e4ca265763`
  );
  console.log(city);

  Content(city, api);

  const apiFtecher = () => {
    return setapi(
      `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=${city},LK&mode=json&appid=5c4420d5c8a61c16e5ee37e4ca265763`
    );
  };

  return (
    <div style={{ width: 300 }}>
      <Autocomplete
        freeSolo
        id="free-solo-2-demo"
        disableClearable
        options={Cities.map((option) => option.name)}
        renderInput={(params) => (
          <TextField
            {...params}
            label="city"
            margin="normal"
            variant="outlined"
            InputProps={{ ...params.InputProps, type: "search" }}
            onChange={(e) => setcity(e.target.value)}
            onBlur={(e) => setcity(e.target.value)}
          />
        )}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default SearchBar;
```

Comment: You want to call the API on EVERY change to the text field? Or you only want to call it on blur?

Comment: i wan to cal it on blur

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a need for the `city` state variable.

To call `apiFtecher`[sic] on every change of the input, you would do something like this:

```
const apiFtecher = e => {
 const city = e.target.value;
 return (
  setapi(`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=${city},LK&mode=json&appid=5c4420d5c8a61c16e5ee37e4ca265763`)
  );
}
```

And update the element to:

```
<TextField
        {...params}
        label="city"
        margin="normal"
        variant="outlined"
        InputProps={{ ...params.InputProps, type: 'search' }}
        onChange={apiFtecher}
      />
```